# Undefined Index ao recuperar dados do POST

Tags: php

Estou a criar uma loja online, e preciso de adicionar os produtos no site através da BD.

Para facilitar, quero criar uma parte gráfica, coisa que já esta feita, mas nas minhas variáveis da-me o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: product_code in /home/i12184/public_html/admin.php on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: product_name in /home/i12184/public_html/admin.php on line 5
>   Notice: Undefined index: $product_desc in /home/i12184/public_html/admin.php on line 6
>   Notice: Undefined index: $product_img_name in /home/i12184/public_html/admin.php on line 7
>   Notice: Undefined index: price in /home/i12184/public_html/admin.php on line 8

### Meu código:

```
$product_code = $_POST['product_code'];
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_desc = $_POST['$product_desc'];
$product_img_name = $_POST['$product_img_name'];
$price =$_POST['price'];

$insert ='insert into products (product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price)
   Values("'.$product_code.'", "'.$product_name.'", "'.$product_desc.'",
       "'.$product_img_name.'", "'.$price.'")';

mysql_query($insert);
```

### Html

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post" onsubmit="formsubmit(this)">     
    Codigo do Produto: <input type="text" name="product_code" /><br /><br />
    Nome do Produto: <input type="text" name="product_name" /><br /><br />
    Descricao do Produto: <input type="tinytext" name="product_desc" /><br /><br />
    Nome da Imagem do Produto: <input type="text" name="product_img_name" /><br /><br />
    Preco: <input type="decimal" name="price" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

<script>    
    function formsubmit(form) 
    {       
        form.submit();  
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Pelo o que está dizendo no seu erro `$_POST['product_code']` não existe. Poderia postar o resultado do `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: @ErlonCharles de momento não o consigo fazer :/

Comment: Poderia colocar parte do form html?

Comment: Poderia complementar e adicionar esse seu método javascript `formsubmit()` ? Só para corrigir já: `$_POST['$product_desc'];` observe que você está usando o $ na frente do nome. E aqui também: `$_POST['$product_img_name'];`. Retire esses $ e ficará assim: `$_POST['product_img_name']; $_POST['product_desc'];`

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft feito :) realmente nao tinha reparado no '$' muito obrigado

Comment: Foi resolvido:?

Comment: Ja funciona Obrigado a todos simplesmente movi o codigo php para outro ficheiro.

Answer (score 3):

Notice: **"undefined index"**:

Para entender esse tipo de mensagem, observe o exemplo abaixo:

```
$x = $y + 10;
```

Executando esse script, que valor deve conter a variável $x?

Você deve responder, impossível dizer, não sei qual é o valor da variável $y. Para o PHP a resposta é a mesma, para ele está sendo feito a seguinte operação internamente:

$x = valor indefinido + 10;

A maneira correta e fazer a seguinte operação:

```
$y = 5;
$x = $y + 10;
```

Ou

```
$y = 0;
$x = $y + 10;
```

Toda vez que é feita uma operação com uma variável "valor indefinido" o PHP exibe a mensagem Notice: Undefined variable.

Muitas vezes os nossos problemas de programação são mais complexos, pois estamos trabalhando com variáveis passadas por SESSION, GET, POST e outros métodos, para trabalhar dessa forma e necessário avaliar a condição da variável, por exemplo:

```
if(!isset($y))
$y = 0;
```

Esse script verifica se a variável existe, se a variável não existir é atribuído zero.

Pode ocorrer o mesmo erro quanto estamos trabalhando com arrays e tentamos acessar uma posição que não existe, por exemplo:

```
$info_funcionario = array("nome" => "Patrick Espake", "profissao" => "Programador");
echo $info_funcionario["email"];
```

No script acima estou tentando acessar o índice "email" no array, esse índice não existe e o PHP exibe a mensagem Notice: Undefined index email.

Você pode fazer a seguinte afirmação: "Já programei assim em PHP e nunca apareceu esse erro!".

O que acontece é que essas notificações de erros podem ser configuradas no php.ini, muitos programadores em ambiente de desenvolvimento deixam configurado para exibir todos os erros e em ambiente de produção deixam configurado para não exibir os erros de notificação.

Para configurar o php.ini para mostrar todos os erros, você deve deixar a cláusula error_reporting da seguinte forma:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

Para configurar o php.ini para não exibir as mensagens de notificação você deve deixar da seguinte forma:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Em outras linguagens de programação uma variável não inicializada pode conter qualquer coisa, no PHP é considerado como nulo ou como 0 em uma operação aritmética.

Além disso, é mais rápido escrever:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Do que:

```
if isset($_GET['id'])) echo $_GET['id'];
```

Em casos extremos você pode usar o @ para ocultar as mensagens de notificação.

```
echo @$_GET['id'];
```

Fonte:http://www.htmlstaff.org/ver.php?id=11074

Answer (score 2):

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é validação de dados, pois o array do POST só recebe os dados dos campos que tiveram dados postados. A validação pode ser client-site, ou seja, no lado do cliente, que é o navegador, por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="product_code" required="required" />
<!-- Observe o required, não permitirá que seja postado em branco -->
```

E/ou pode ser feita a validação no server-side, ou seja, no PHP, exemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['product_code']) === true) {
    $product_code = $_POST['product_code'];
} else {
    $product_code = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para complementar e ser um pouco mais direto, a questão é que você está usando apóstrofos (`'...'`) e colocando variáveis dentro deles assim `'$minha_variavel'`, porém variáveis só executam dentro de aspas `"$minha_variavel"`, no caso do seu exemplo você não precisa de aspas, bastaria usar assim `[$minha_variavel]`

O resultado deve ser algo como:

```
$product_desc = $_POST[$product_desc];
$product_img_name = $_POST[$product_img_name];
```

Porém ao analisar o seu código ele na verdade parece ter outra intenção, pois provavelmente o código que adicionei irá causar o *warning* `Undefined variable`, olhando para o html você tem os seguintes inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="product_code" /> 
<input type="text" name="product_name" /> 
<input type="tinytext" name="product_desc" /> 
<input type="text" name="product_img_name" /> 
<input type="decimal" name="price" />
```

Nenhum deles realmente possui cifrão `$`, portanto o correto é usar assim:

```
$product_code = $_POST['product_code'];
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];//Removido o $
$product_img_name = $_POST['product_img_name'];//Removido o $
$price =$_POST['price'];
```