# Notice: Undefined index: tipotopo

Tags: php

Bom dia, migrei o site de um cliente da com php 5.3 para uma hospedagem com php 5.5 (não tem como setar php 5.3 pelo php.ini) e está retornando os seguintes erros ao acessar a página.

```
Notice: Undefined index: tipotopo in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: tipo in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: idcolecao in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: acao in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: portal in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: pagina in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: filtro in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: idioma in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: erro in /home/bluce130/sistema/include-topo.php on line 24
```

Código include-topo.php

```
<?
session_start();
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
require_once("../scripts/conexao.php");
require_once("../scripts/funcoes.php");
require_once("../scripts/mysql.php");
require_once("../scripts/img.canvas.php");
require_once("../scripts/paginacao.php");

$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");
if($page != 'index') require_once("verifica.php");

$tipotopo   = seguranca($_GET['tipotopo']);
if($tipotopo) $_SESSION['tipo'] = $tipotopo;
$tipomoda   = $_SESSION['tipo'];

$id         = intval($_GET["id"]);
$idcolecao  = intval($_GET["idcolecao"]);
$acao       = seguranca($_GET["acao"]);
$portal     = seguranca($_GET["portal"]);
$pagina     = seguranca($_GET["pagina"]);
$filtro     = seguranca($_GET["filtro"]);
$idioma     = seguranca($_GET["idioma"]);
$erro       = seguranca($_GET["erro"]);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Administração</title>
<meta name="Author" content="www.dataprisma.com.br" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/sistema.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jcrop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var page        = '<?=$page?>';
var tipomoda    = '<?=$tipomoda?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fckeditor/fckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/sistema.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<? if($erro == 1){ ?>
alert('Um ou mais arquivos não foram enviados, extensão não permitida!');
<? } ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carregando"><img src="../img/sistema/carregando.gif" class="vimg" /> Processando...</div>
<div class="center" style="position:relative; width:1000px; margin:15px auto 0 auto">
<table width="1000" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border:#999 1px solid; border-bottom:none;">
    <? if($page != 'index'){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="175" valign="top">
        <strong style="color:#666">Logado em:</strong>&nbsp;
        <select name="tipotopo" id="tipotopo">
            <option value="F" <? if($tipomoda == 'F') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Feminino</option>
            <option value="M" <? if($tipomoda == 'M') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Masculino</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td width="668" valign="top"><input type="button" name="bt-tipotopo" id="bt-tipotopo" value="OK" /></td>
        <td width="95" align="right"><a href="<?=$http?>"><img src="../img/sistema/happy-logo.jpg" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="3" id="menu" style="padding:0 5px">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php" <? if($page == 'home') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="background.php" <? if($page == 'background') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Background</a></li>
                <li><a href="clipping.php" <? if($page == 'clipping') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Clipping</a></li>
                <li><a href="colecao.php" <? if($page == 'colecao' || $page == 'campanha') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Coleção</a></li>
                <li><a href="onde-comprar.php" <? if($page == 'onde-comprar') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Onde Comprar</a></li>
                <!--li><a href="imprensa.php" <? if($page == 'imprensa') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Imprensa</a></li-->
                <li><a href="empresa.php" <? if($page == 'empresa') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Empresa</a></li>
                <li><a href="newsletter.php" <? if($page == 'newsletter') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Newsletter</a></li>
                <li><a href="contatos.php" <? if($page == 'contatos') echo 'class="hover"'; ?>>Contatos</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php" style="color:#d33">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?
    } else {
        echo '<tr align="center" class="menu"><td>';
        echo '<h2 style="color:#2c2a2b;margin:0">Para acessar a administração, preencha seu login e senha:</h2>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Código index.php

```
<? include("include-topo.php"); ?>
<div class="center conteudo">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?=$sistema?>autentica.php">
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle"><strong>Qual site deseja administrar?</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
        <select name="tipo" id="tipo" style="width:100%">
            <option value="F">Feminino</option>
            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle"><strong>Login:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="login" type="text" id="login" size="35" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle"><strong>Senha:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="senha" type="password" id="senha" size="35" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Entrar" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<? include("include-rodape.php"); ?>
```

Como estou aprendendo aos poucos a lidar com php, não consegui resolver esse problema sozinho.

Comment: Para evitar este erro, basta testar se este campo do quadro foi inicializado com a função isset().

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58355/quando-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-utilizar-o-isset

Comment: Acredito que ambas as perguntas indicadas acima respondem a questão. No mais, acho irônico ter uma função com nome de  `seguranca` se está usando um PHP obsoleto e oficialmente inseguro como o PHP 5.5 e PHP 5.3.

Comment: Talvez, seja melhor duplicada desta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/como-resolver-um-notice-undefined-index?rq=1

Comment: eu acho essa mais esclarecedora https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56015/undefined-index-ao-recuperar-dados-do-post

Comment: Boa tarde, é que meu conhecimento é 0 em php, eu trabalho somente com hospedagem. Fui migrar esta de um cliente e o site dele começou a dar este problema. Eu andei dando uma lida nos links mencionados por vocês porém mesmo assim não consegui resolver meu problema =(