# Erro ao usar class para filtro por nomes de alunos

Tags: php, mysql, funções, classes, filtro

Estou tentando fazer uma função para pesquisar por nome do aluno no bando de dados.

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: filtro in C:\meuphp\teste\pesquisa_aluno.php on line 7

```
   <?php 

    require 'conexao.php';
    include 'classe_aluno.php';

    $exibindo= new Aluno($mysql);
    $filtrado=$exibindo->exibirUm($_POST['filtro']);?>
```

A linha que mostra o erro é:

```
$filtrado=$exibindo->exibirUm($_POST['filtro']);?>
```

O segundo erro é

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Aluno::exibirUm() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\meuphp\teste\pesquisa_aluno.php on line 7 and defined in C:\meuphp\teste\classe_aluno.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\meuphp\teste\pesquisa_aluno.php(7): Aluno->exibirUm(NULL) #1 {main} thrown

```
public function exibirUm(string $filtro){

        $exibir=$this->mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE nome LIKE  ?");
        $exibir->bind_param('s',$filtro);
        $exibir->execute();
        $filtrado=$exibir->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

        return $filtrado;
    }
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Undefined Index ao recuperar dados do POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56015/undefined-index-ao-recuperar-dados-do-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que ao abrir a página pela primeira vez nenhum POST foi feito, portanto `$_POST['filtro']` não existe. Consequentemente, o método `exibirUm`, que espera receber uma string, recebe `NULL`.

Para resolver esse problema, faça o filtro na base de dados somente quando estiver recebendo os dados do formulário. Algo como

```php
if (isset($_POST['filtro']) === true) {
  $filtrado = $exibindo->exibirUm($_POST['filtro']);
}
```

Comment: Me ajudou bastante isso muito obrigado resolveu meu problema. Como posso estar usando isso na variavel $filtrado? Estou passando resultado para uma tabela do próprio html "table",            <th><?php echo $filtrado['nome']; ?></th>

Comment: @Medivh, não conheço os seus métodos, mas vc pode, antes de exibir o resultado, verificar se não é um POST (ou filtrado não está setado) e nesse caso não exibir a tabela com resultado. No caso de ser um post, mas nenhum resultado ser encontrado, apresentar uma mensagem. Por fim, caso tenha resultado, apresenta a tabela.