# Não consigo entender/encontrar o erro no código php

Tags: php, html, html5, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um sistema de cadastro de clientes e quando executo o .php ele simplesmente aparece esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código php:

```
<?php

      $login = $_POST['inputEmail'];
      $senha = MD5($_POST['inputSenha']);
      $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','postgres','root');
      $db = mysql_select_db('SrVisao');
      $query_select = "SELECT inputEmail FROM usuarios WHERE inputEmail = '$inputEmail'";
      $select = mysql_query($query_select,$connect);
      $array = mysql_fetch_array($select);
      $logarray = $array['inputEmail'];

      if($inputEmail == "" || $inputEmail == null){
        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        alert('O campo email deve ser preenchido');window.location.href='
        cadastroCliente3.html';</script>";

      }else{
        if($logarray == $inputEmail){

          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
          alert('Esse login já existe');window.location.href='
          cadastroCliente3.html';</script>";
          die();
        }else{
          $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (inputEmail,inputSenha) VALUES ('$inputEmail','$inputSenha')";
          $insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);

          if($insert){
            echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.
            href='login.html'</script>";
          }else{
            echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse usuário');window.location
            .href='cadastroCliente3.html'</script>";
          }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: acho que você deveria usa mysqli_connect() ao inves de mysql_connect() veja a diferença: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63331/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-mysql-connect-e-mysqli-connect-em-php

Answer (score 1):

As duas primeiras mensagens são notificações de que o PHP não encontrou os índices informados dentro de `$_POST` (veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56022/165800) para mais informações). Você deve verificar se essas informações estão sendo passadas corretamente.

Em relação às duas últimas mensagens, é porque você está chamando uma função que foi descontinuada no PHP. Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173038/165800) para mais detalhes.